# Wifi driver crashes every 1 minute Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, drivers, wireless-router

My mothers laptop is experiencing issues when connecting to the Internet provided by Mediacom.

After exactly 1 minute (according to her) of being connected, the wifi driver (Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165  v18.12.1.2) crashes which requires PC restart.

There have been 2 different error codes upon crashing with the most common one being.

> This device cannot start. (Code 10)
>
> {Operation Failed} The requestion operation was unsuccessful.

we have also seen

> Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer. (Code 45)
>
> To fix this problem, reconnect this hardware device to the computer.

The PC in question is usually connected to the wifi provided by Comcast.
An alternate PC (running Vista :/) was connected to the Mediacom WiFi and had no problems.

Also I should mention when use a wired connection to the Mediacom Internet there are no problems.

I am thinking it is an issue with the PC driver, but I want to here from someone who actually knows. :)

My question is/are
What could be causing this? What areas should I look into?

Comment: Not the ISP.  This is local to the system.  firmware and drivers, update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your ISP has anything to do with it. Have you tried reinstalling the drivers? [Here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/intel-wi-fi-products/intel-wireless-3100-series/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3165.html) is a link to Intel's site where you can find the drivers. I know you said you think it is an issue with the drivers, but it is not intrusive or difficult to re-install the drivers to troubleshoot it.

Did this start happening after a specific change in hardware or software? If there was a change in software or hardware around time time the issue started, look there.